# Abrir arquivos de uma certa extensão no meu programa

Tags: c#, arquivo, extensão

Estou fazendo um aplicativo no Visual Studio, com a intenção dele trabalhar com arquivos de extensão própria (`.rmt`, sujeito a mudança) e possa abrir ele depois.

Quero que quando o usuário der um duplo-clique nos arquivos com esta extensão, o sistema abra o arquivo usando meu aplicativo, de forma a este poder processar o arquivo conforme eu quiser.

Como posso vincular esta extensão ao meu aplicativo?

Comment: e o que você já fez? Qual erro está encontrando?

Comment: então @Ricardo , nada... pretendia começar por aí, mas talvez exportar esse arquivo como uma pasta para um outro diretório seja uma opção viável. mas gostaria de poder exportar e importar essa pasta, para abrir em outro pc, por exemplo.

Comment: Me parece que a dúvida principal é a associação do arquivo com o programa. Nesse caso, caso o OP tenha afinidade com inglês, tem essa excelente resposta no Stack Overflow em inglês: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c

Se alguém se prestar a traduzir, seria ótimo para a comunidade.

Comment: @Pablo só uma observação, é bom lembrar que no Windows 10 mudou a maneira de lidar com associações de arquivo. Aparentemente isto não foi coberto na questão indicada. Para versões anteriores, parece suficiente.

Comment: @Bacco Mas mesmo para aplicações Win32?

Comment: começar pela parte de "criar o arquivo de extensão própria"

Comment: @Pablo sim, com o 10 a MS nao quer que o programa dê override por janela própria, mas sim por uma janela padrão do OS, ao final da instalação

Comment: @Bacco Saquei. Parece que o trabalho para responder essa pergunta será maior ainda. =/

Comment: @vhoyer ao salvar o arquivo, você pode usar a extensão que desejar. Isso não muda nada. O problema é associar esta extensão ao seu programa, que é a indicação do Pablo. Ao clicar no programa, uma vez associado, seu programa vai receber o nome do arquivo como se seu programa tivesse sido chamado assim: "programaDoVhoier.exe meuarquivo.rmt". Eu creio que você deveria focar a pergunta na associação.

Comment: bom então, primeiro teria como abrir um arquivo compactado como zip, mas com outro nome de extensão?

Comment: @vhoyer seu programa já compacta e descompacta o formato desejado? Isso seria um 4o problema :) - Lembre-se que você deve fazer perguntas separadas para cada parte do problema, senão fica complicado. Este site não é um forum, mas sim um site de perguntas objetivas que recebem respostas objetivas. E você pode ir perguntando uma coisa por vez, e fazendo novas perguntas à vontade, à medida que for resolvendo cada etapa. Desde que as perguntas se encaixem no formato do site, dá pra você fazer várias.

Comment: entendi, perdão se eu não tinha compreendido direito o formato do site... vou tentar não postar mais esse tipo de coisa, então por hora, teria uma sugestão para consertar essa pergunta? e não ainda não, pq quando comecei a pensar sobre isso vim pro stack, mas por tudo que li antes de fazer a pergunta, é relativamente fácil compactar e descompactar, então, não seria um "problema"

Comment: @Bacco então acho que vou remover a pergunta e criar outras, obrigado pela a ajuda e desculpa pelo transtorno...

Comment: @vhoyer tomei a liberdade de editar sua pergunta focando na associação dos arquivos, mas se não gostar de como ficou, você pode clicar [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/105515/revisions) e escolher a opção de Reverter, na sua versão anterior (5) para descartar as mudanças.

Comment: não, obrigado @Bacco eu ia tentar editar, mas você foi mais rápido

Comment: @vhoyer fique à vontade para editar por cima e deixar com as suas palavras se achar necessário. Só procurei deixar um problema único na questão, até para facilitar para quem for responder. E o bom é que com perguntas separadas, as respostas além de poderem te ajudar, podem ser achadas mais facilmente por outros com o mesmo problema. E estando separadas, pessoas com conhecimentos diferentes podem ajudar melhor nas partes que dominam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Próprio [ClickOnce cria extenções](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb892924.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), mas você também pode criar uma chave no registro para associar uma extensão de arquivo para seu executável. Primeiramente, declare esse método estático:

```
public static void SetAssociation(string Extension, string KeyName, string OpenWith, string FileDescription)
{
   RegistryKey BaseKey;
   RegistryKey OpenMethod;
   RegistryKey Shell;
   RegistryKey CurrentUser;

   BaseKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(Extension);
   BaseKey.SetValue("", KeyName);

   OpenMethod = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(KeyName);
   OpenMethod.SetValue("", FileDescription);
   OpenMethod.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "\"" + OpenWith + "\",0");
   Shell = OpenMethod.CreateSubKey("Shell");
   Shell.CreateSubKey("edit").CreateSubKey("command").SetValue("", "\"" + OpenWith + "\"" + " \"%1\"");
   Shell.CreateSubKey("open").CreateSubKey("command").SetValue("", "\"" + OpenWith + "\"" + " \"%1\"");
   BaseKey.Close();
   OpenMethod.Close();
   Shell.Close();

   CurrentUser = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ucs");
   CurrentUser = CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("UserChoice", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights.FullControl);
   CurrentUser.SetValue("Progid", KeyName, RegistryValueKind.String);
   CurrentUser.Close();
}
```

Ai, você pode associar programaticamente seu aplicativo usando esse método:

```
SetAssociation(".rmt", "Nome_da_extensao", Application.ExecutablePath, "Minha extenção .rmt");
```

Peguei essa resposta desse link [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681878/associate-file-extension-with-application).